# What is "ld -Ttext" option doing?

Tags: linker, kernel, ld

I am following [this half-completed tutorial](https://www.cs.bham.ac.uk/~exr/lectures/opsys/10_11/lectures/os-dev.pdf) to develop a simple OS. One step (on page 50) is to compile a simple kernel with `$ld -o kernel.bin -Ttext 0x1000 kernel.o --oformat binary`. However I don't really understand what is the option `-Ttext` doing.

To make the question specific, why in the following experiment are md5s of `kernel_1000.bin` & `kernel.bin` equal, `kernel_1001.bin` & `kernel_1009.bin` equal, and `kernel_1007.bin` & `kernel_1017.bin` equal, while all other pairs are not equal?

## My experiment

I tried to compile several different kernels with different `-Ttext` like the in the following `Makefile`:

```
...
kernel.o: kernel.c
    gcc -ffreestanding -c kernel.c

kernel.bin: kernel.o
    ld -o $@ kernel.o --oformat binary

kernel_1000.bin: kernel.o
    ld -o $@ -Ttext 0x1000 kernel.o --oformat binary

kernel_1001.bin: kernel.o
    ld -o $@ -Ttext 0x1001 kernel.o --oformat binary
...
```

And then I checked their md5:

```
$ ls *.bin | xargs md5sum
d9248440a2c816e41527686cdb5118e4  kernel_1000.bin
65db5ab465301da1176b523dec387a40  kernel_1001.bin
819a5638827494a4556b7a96ee6e14b2  kernel_1007.bin
d9248440a2c816e41527686cdb5118e4  kernel_1008.bin
65db5ab465301da1176b523dec387a40  kernel_1009.bin
216b24060abce034911642acfa880403  kernel_1015.bin
e92901b1d12d316c564ba7916abca20c  kernel_1016.bin
819a5638827494a4556b7a96ee6e14b2  kernel_1017.bin
d9248440a2c816e41527686cdb5118e4  kernel.bin
```

## kernel.c

```
void main() {
  char* video_memory = (char*) 0xb8000;
  *video_memory = 'X';
}
```

## Development environment

```
$ gcc -v
Using built-in specs.
COLLECT_GCC=gcc
COLLECT_LTO_WRAPPER=/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.9/lto-wrapper
Target: x86_64-linux-gnu
Configured with: ../src/configure -v --with-pkgversion='Debian 4.9.2-10' --with-bugurl=file:///usr/share/doc/gcc-4.9/README.Bugs --enable-languages=c,c++,java,go,d,fortran,objc,obj-c++ --prefix=/usr --program-suffix=-4.9 --enable-shared --enable-linker-build-id --libexecdir=/usr/lib --without-included-gettext --enable-threads=posix --with-gxx-include-dir=/usr/include/c++/4.9 --libdir=/usr/lib --enable-nls --with-sysroot=/ --enable-clocale=gnu --enable-libstdcxx-debug --enable-libstdcxx-time=yes --enable-gnu-unique-object --disable-vtable-verify --enable-plugin --with-system-zlib --disable-browser-plugin --enable-java-awt=gtk --enable-gtk-cairo --with-java-home=/usr/lib/jvm/java-1.5.0-gcj-4.9-amd64/jre --enable-java-home --with-jvm-root-dir=/usr/lib/jvm/java-1.5.0-gcj-4.9-amd64 --with-jvm-jar-dir=/usr/lib/jvm-exports/java-1.5.0-gcj-4.9-amd64 --with-arch-directory=amd64 --with-ecj-jar=/usr/share/java/eclipse-ecj.jar --enable-objc-gc --enable-multiarch --with-arch-32=i586 --with-abi=m64 --with-multilib-list=m32,m64,mx32 --enable-multilib --with-tune=generic --enable-checking=release --build=x86_64-linux-gnu --host=x86_64-linux-gnu --target=x86_64-linux-gnu
Thread model: posix
gcc version 4.9.2 (Debian 4.9.2-10) 
$ uname -a
Linux localhost 3.16.0-4-amd64 #1 SMP Debian 3.16.7-ckt20-1+deb8u1 (2015-12-14) x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The `-Ttext` option puts the [.text](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_segment) section of your program by the given address. For example if you are compile this assembly code:

```
section .text
global _start
_start:
    mov al, '!'
    jmp l
l:  mov ah, 0x0e
    mov bh, 0x00
    mov bl, 0x07

    int 0x10
    jmp $

times 510-($-$$) db 0

db 0x55
db 0xaa
```

with:

```
nasm -f elf64 -o test.o test.S
ld -o test test.o
```

And will look on it with the `objdump`, you will see that it was linked by default address, something around `0x0000000000400000` for the `x86_64`:

```
~$ objdump -D test

test:     file format elf64-x86-64


Disassembly of section .text:

0000000000400080 <_start>:
  400080:   b0 21                   mov    $0x21,%al
  400082:   eb 00                   jmp    400084 <l>

0000000000400084 <l>:
  400084:   b4 0e                   mov    $0xe,%ah
  ...
  ...
  ...
```

And all addresses in the program (at least in the `.text` section) will be relative to this address. If you will add the `-Ttext 1000` option, you will see:

~$ objdump -D test

```
test:     file format elf64-x86-64


Disassembly of section .text:

0000000000001000 <_start>:
    1000:   b0 21                   mov    $0x21,%al
    1002:   eb 00                   jmp    1004 <l>

0000000000001004 <l>:
    1004:   b4 0e                   mov    $0xe,%ah
```

That you program will be linked to start at `0x1000` address and all addresses (including jmp and etc.) will be relative to the `0x1000` to.

This important for two things. In short words, when an operating system kernel loads your program, it loads your executable which is in [elf](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Executable_and_Linkable_Format) format or in other binary format and reads where the `.text` section starts. In our case, you can link your `kernel.bin` as you want, because there are no loaders as an operating system kernel and your are master of all memory space.

So if you will link your `kernel.bin` to start at `0x1000`, you will know where the code starts to work (of course if it will actually loaded at this place in memory) and if you know the base address of your code, you can get all addresses inside it, something like `my_label_inside_program - _start`.